# Issue while reading a JSON script array output using Foreach loop in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an array output from ACTIVITY script like this

```
Input json array
  {
  "result":[
  {
  "Val":[
  {"pqr":1,"srt":2},
  {"pqr":1,"srt":2}
  ]
  }
  ]
  }
```

How can I iterate  this nested json object using a Foreach loop. I am getting error while I use @activity(script).output .result. Val to  get the array values.
Error: The length cannot be evaluated because property value doesn't exist

Comment: @ RakeshGovindula-MT

Comment: @wBob yr right ,sure this is corrcet json{
  "result":[
  {
  "Val":[
  {"pqr":1,"srt":2},
  {"pqr":1,"srt":2}
  ]
  }
  ]
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your For Each activity **Items** to:

```
@activity('Script').output.result[0].Val
```

and use it within the activity using the `@item()` syntax, e.g.

```
@string(item().pqr)
```

Comment: @string(item().Val[0]. pqr)->Here the o/p is not looping   ,it is only taking first array value I want to get both the values of pqr inside for loop

Comment: Thank  a lot ,i got stuck on this for a while

Comment: Please upvote and make as answer (green tick) of this has been helpful!

Comment: Sure wBob I have one query also,I am getting my xml response from restpi,But the columns names i getting from xml response through lookup activity  arein fformat @pqr,@xyz like this.So I am unable to read the values inside foreach .(@string(item().@BookedLossu) ->showing error so how to read the column nvalues from xml

Comment: That’s a separate question really.  Why not upvote and mark this one as answered, and open a new one with your sample data and expected results?  I am sure someone will be able to help you.

Comment: LESS reputation once i have it ,i can upvote Thank you btw